# How can I make a "doubleclickable" launcher/program in Fedora 33?

Tags: fedora, gnome, gui

I use Fedora 33 every day. I use the default GUI. To start a program, for all CLI utilities I use the terminal, and for GUI programs, I often hit the "Windows" key on the keyboard which allows me to type in e.g. "Text Editor" (or even just "Text") and hit enter, and it starts.

The thing is, in the latter case, I have no idea what's really going on "under the hood." Is there a way to create a file on e.g. my Desktop where when I double click it, it runs? I did some searching and I found out about `.desktop` files. However, these do not have the expected behavior because I went into /usr/share/applications and found `.desktop` files there which correspond with various applications I have installed. I tried moving some of these into /home/me/Desktop and `chmod 755`ing them. But when I double-click them, they end up being opened in my hex editor, rather than launching the program. When I try to do `./firefox.desktop`, for example in Terminal (this is not my intended use, but I gave it a try anyway), I get a laundry list of errors and firefox does not start.

I would also like to ask, is it possible for example a scheme such as `file:///home/me/Desktop/firefox.desktop` could launch firefox? How can I accomplish this? I apologize if any of my terminology is confusing - I am not sure what this subject is called in Linux GUI world.

Answer (score 0):

The "Windows" key (also known as ***Super***, ***Meta*** or ***Start***) lists all the applications indicated by the `.desktop` files you mentioned.

Those `.desktop` files provide certain information to the Desktop Environment (Gnome in the case of Fedora), like the **Name** of the app, the **Executable** to run when you click on it and the related **Icon**.

The default system path for `.desktop` files is `/usr/share/applications/`, while the path for your current user will be `~/.local/share/applications/`.

If you wish to create a custom launcher, lets say you created another Firefox profile called ***custom***, you would create the following `.desktop` file in your user's profile path:

```
vim ~/.local/share/applications/firefox-custom.desktop
```

And inside the file, you could have something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Firefox Custom
Exec=/usr/bin/firefox -P "custom" -no-remote
Icon=firefox
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
```

Once you created this file, when you press the ***Super*** key (or click on the **Activities** and "Show Applications" icon) and type "Firefox" for example, you will see two Firefox icons, the one created above will have the "Firefox Custom" name.

**NOTE**: you need to create the **custom** profile with `firefox --ProfileManager` for the example above to work.

You can look at other `.desktop` files examples in the default system path mentioned above (`/usr/share/applications`), and copy them to your local user path to edit them if you wish.

Just to make it clear: You *don't click the .desktop file itself*, this file is a reference only for the Desktop Environment to display the application when showing the dashboard/activities/menu. If you wish to create a **clickable executable file**, you would probably need to create an executable file type (`.sh` for example), give it exec permissions (`chmod +x`) and modify the configuration of Nautilus (the file manager, although *I think this option no longer exists*) to run those type of files instead of editing them on double clicking.